# Python dynamic function design based on input

Tags: python, function, design-patterns, structure

Suppose I have 26 functions and one of them calculate some formulas.
Let's call them function_a, function_b, ..., function_z.

In my main function, I need to choose which function_{a...z} to use based on the given input.

I wrote the following function.

```
def main(input):
    result = 0
    if input == 'a':
        result = function_a()
    elif input == 'b':
        result = function_b()
    ...

    elif input == 'z':
        result = function_z()
```

Or I have a long dictionary like below, and choose the function to use based on the input.

```
{'a': function_a, 'b': function_b, ... , 'z': function_z}
```

**However, are there any better designs / structures?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Python also has a switch-case like structure now called [`match`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#match-statements). Which is not an entirely new design or structure, it just feels a little cleaner imo.

```py
def main(input):
    result = 0
    match input:
        case 'a':
            result = function_a()
        case 'b':
            result = function_b()
```

Answer (score 1):

Even considering the introduction of [`match` statements in Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#match-statements), I find the dictionary approach to be effective for simple scenarios.

Adding new "match/case" blocks is as easy as adding another key-value pair. And you can even use a `try`/`except` block to catch the `KeyError` and handle invalid input.

Example:

```
def main(input_string):
    try:
        result = {
            'a': function_a, 
            'b': function_b,
            # add other cases here
            'z': function_z,
        }[input_string]()
    except KeyError:
        print(f'Got an invalid input: {input_string}')
    # ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "getattr", add all functions in one class and pass this class to getattr and also the letter:

```
class Definations:
    def function_a():
        return 'output: a'

    def function_b():
        return 'output: b'
  
    
def main(input):
  obj = getattr(Definations, f'function_{input}')
  return obj()
    
print(main('a'))
```